# How to merge two data frames and fill with different options based on coincidences

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frame `y` and `z`

```
y <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), gene = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "c"))
z <- data.frame(A = c(2,6,3), B = c(8,4,9), C=c(1,6,2))
rownames(z) <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

So for y I have a table with patients ID and gene for each patients and in Z I have the same patients IDs in the first row and a list of genes with a specific value (which is not important here). The genes in y are in z, but in z there are genes that are not included in y.
What I want to do is to `merge` this frames and have something like this:

```
       a   b   c
A      1   1   1 
B      1   0   1
```

So for each patient, if the genes in `z` are also in `y,` fill with 1 and if not, fill with 0

I don't really know how to handle this, any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Do the `A`, `B`, `C` columns in `z` have any relation to the result?

Comment: When asking a question, write reproducible examples (something we can easily cut and paste in our own R session).  You want us to have easy acces to your `y` and `z` object.  Look at the function `dput`, it might help.

Comment: That being said, you'll want to cast or spread your data, merge it, and cast or spread it again.  To do so, if you're a tidyverse fan, try `tidyr::pivot_wider` or `tidyr::pivot_longer`.  If you're more old school, `reshape2::dcast` or `reshape2::melt`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and suggestion about reproducibility, of course you are totally right and I will definitely consider it next time. Thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made RE from your question (add this to your question next time):

```
y <- data.frame(ID = c("id_A", "id_A", "id_A", "id_B", "id_B"), gene = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "c"))
z <- data.frame(id_A = c(2,6,3), id_B = c(8,4,9), id_C=c(1,6,2))
rownames(z) <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

The idea here is to `pivot_longer` your tables so you can join than easily.

To do so, you first need to make your rownames into a field:

```
z <- tibble::rownames_to_column(z, "gene")
```

Then, you pivot longer you `z` table:

```
library(tidyr)
z_long <- pivot_longer(z, starts_with("id_"), names_to = "ID")
```

and join it with your `y` table:

```
library(dplyr)
table_join <- left_join(y, z_long)
```

Finally, you just have to calculate the frequencies:

```
table(table_join$ID, table_join$gene)
   
       a b c
  id_A 1 1 1
  id_B 1 0 1
```

Comment: The "main problem" is I can't create a z_long because original z has near 56.000 rows (gene names)

Comment: I don't think that is a problem.  If you have enough memory (RAM) on your computer, the number of genes should not be a problem.  As for writing the line of the script, I updated my question using `starts_with` to select more easily the IDs.  Try it and if it doesn't work, update the reproducible example so it represent better your problem.

Comment: yes, the problem was the RAM memory but I figured it out and your code works perfectly. Thank you